# Visual Studio C# Console App (.NET Core) Template Different

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console-application, visual-studio-templates

Everytime I open a new project for C# Console App I get the following [template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uS8OY.jpg):

I believe I somehow have updated the original template with one of my intro to C# tutorial practice. Is there anyway to reset the template?

Update:
Should the template not look like [this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndlXE.jpg)

Comment: Nope, that's what I get as well in an out-of-the-box install.

Comment: Shouldn't the template be something like this:

using System;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}

Comment: You are asking if the `Main` method should be empty? Apparently not with .NET Core... .NET Standard it is, I'm not sure why Microsoft decided to do it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET Core's Console Project is exactly like you posted, this is the default project template from Microsoft.

If it really bothers you, you can edit the template. [Microsoft provides instructions on how to do it here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185319.aspx).